# Exported photoshop image is 'darker/ stronger' when viewed on mobile

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, images, photo-editing

I noticed that the colors of the exported image from photoshop, when viewed from mobile, is 'stronger' or 'darker' but are retained when viewed on a computer/ laptop.

I'm unable to send a screenshot of the 'stronger' image since, when sent on the laptop I'm working on, becomes normal.

I tried recreating it still.

This is how it looks like on laptop:
[image]

While this is how it looks on mobile:
[image]

How do I ensure that the colors are the same or at least, almost the same?

Comment: You cannot control how your graphics will look on every device, it's just not possible. You can control your own monitor colors by using a monitor calibration tool. Not sure what your question is.

Comment: Although it's not possible to control the colour fully on all devices, you should make sure images at least have an sRGB colour profile. It's the standard used for colour reproduction on the web. That way, you have the best chance of the colours looking as similar as possible.  Ultimately, you can't control the colours completely because devices are made by different manufacturers, and also on many devices colour settings are something that the user of the device controls. To get colours to look exactly the same on two devices, you'd need to calibrate the displays using a calibration device.

Comment: Try comparing how different webpages look on your laptop and on your mobile.

Answer (score 0):

That could be because your monitor display and mobile display could possibly be different in technology and color reproduction. Some mobiles have better displays than most desktop displays.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're working on a RGB document and not CMYK. And as others said, use a sRGB colour profile. Other than that you can't actually control how it looks on different screens. Good Luck.